# How to load hdp file as background image

Tags: css, hdp, jpeg-xr

I converted jpg files to hdp files to speed up website loading.
I want to load these files via the background property.
However, the hdp file is not loaded from the website.
How can I use an hdp file?
The server is windows10 / Apache2.4

{background:url(./image/file_name.hdp) no-repeat;background-size:cover;}

Comment: It seems to be a problem with a supported browser.

Comment: Once you check your path what you have given.

Comment: why don't you using jpeg, png, jpg files it's also good. do not take too much time to load.

Comment: url link is correct, but showed error "Could not load image."

Comment: once you send your error.

Comment: The error shows up in the window that appears when you press ctrl + shift + I (Chrome)

Comment: That only you have to copy and post in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use like this.

```css
class-name-here {
  background-image: url('./image/file_name.hdp') 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
```